# Trouble updating Android Studio from 3.2 Canary 5 to Canary 6

Tags: android-studio

I'm trying update Android Studio to 3.2 Canary 6, but I got this problem:

**[conflict screenshot]**

[image]

Comment: I installed separate version of Android Studio, file "llvm-symbolizer.exe" has different size, replaced it - Android Studio was updated

Comment: Now I'm trying update to Canary 7 - got same error, replacement "llvm-symbolizer.exe" file don't help